# Make button appear with delay in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this button on my App:

```
<ion-item ng-if="Paid" style="display:none" nav-clear menu-close class="item-icon-right item-assertive" id="avanti" href='#/app/progresses'><i class="icon ion-arrow-right-a"></i> Avanti
</ion-item>
```

I want this button to appear when a video is finished.
How i can do this?

Comment: do you have fixed time of video length?

Comment: yes. Video is around 50 seconds

Comment: ok then you can set time out with ng-show scope varible with 50 sec time when you start video

Comment: or do you have video finish event ? you can set on video finisih also, but you need to use ng-show or ng-hide for your task

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: do you have any event of video start or finished?

Comment: How do you play your video

Answer (score 0):

first need to calculate the video length and pass the length to css, then using css first hide the button and using conditional css you can show the button after completion of video.

```
a[condition] { 
    //code for enable button
}
```